# How to show a value in a dropdown as selected based on some condition in Angular

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have dropdown in my html as below.

```
<select id="floorplans" class="form-control dropdown mb-8" (change)="changeFloorplan($event.target.value)">
   <option *ngFor="let fp of floorplanList" [value]="fp.id">
        {{ fp?.attributes?.name }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Here on some event a particular value should be shown as selected when some condition meets. How can I show the required value as selected in the dropdown?

Comment: You need to assign an ngModel to the select box and set the model value when your condition are met

Comment: Due to some code architecture, we don't use ngModel in our forms and only use 'change' attribute

Comment: [selected] = “condition” I think?